# Can someone explain when sql-delete and sql-delete-all are called in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have a set mapping in Hibernate and need to add special queries for deletes.

Can anyone explain when sql-delete and sql-delete-all are called?

From what I can tell, sql-delete is called everytime the set is changed and sql-delete-all is never called?